# Graphing mathematical functions in java using applets

Tags: java

I'm working this example in my java book, it is supposed to graph a mathematical function and it does work, but i don't understand the last two lines, can someone explain them to me? Assume that `data` is an array of doubles and holds function values for a certain 'range' in this case the range is -pi to pi.

The book has a comment for this little slice of code and i have an idea of what it is doing, but i would like to know exactly why we do the last two lines in this loop.

```
// Scale and translate data values
for (int i = 0; i < d.width; i++) {
        double value = data[i];
        double k = (value - min) / (max - min);
        data[i] = d.height * (1 - k);
    }
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if you found it useful and it answered your question which seems to be the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  In order to draw the graph, the y-values of the function need to be scaled, so that they fit within the height of the area in which they'll be drawn.  So `k` is a scaled version of `y` that's in the range 0 to 1 - that is, the minimum value will map to 0 and the maximum value will map to 1.  Lastly, find the data point to draw by converting `k` into a value between 0 and `d.height`.

Comment: Thank you, i don't fully understand the explanation but i will once i pore over it a bit. Is this a standard way of doing things?

Comment: Pretty standard, yes.  Try out different values of max, min and value, to see what happens with k, and with d.height.  Then you'll understand.

Comment: ok its making more sense. I did a simple example with the numbers {1,2,3,4,5} and in order to map these numbers to 0-1 you do indeed need to do: value - min/difference between max and min. I feel like i have seen this before when dealing with Math.random() for some reason..